# Target element with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is what i'm trying to achieve:
If I click on a month `#month > li >a` it **Fades in the list that has the class name** of **that month. (And hides the other month list so just 1 is shown)** 
It sounds quiet easy but I don't know which would be the correct way to do it with jQuery.

I have this markup:

```
    <ul id="month" class="clearfix">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="calendaractive(this);">January</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="calendaractive(this);">February</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="calendaractive(this);">March</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="day january">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="day february">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="day march">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And this is my script:

```
    function calendaractive(that){
        $(that).find().next('.day').fadeIn();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of passing `calendaractive` the `this` object, you could pass it the name of the month it should activate.

Comment: Does $(that).find().next('.day') return something?

Comment: @Baszz it shouldn't, considering it is looking in the children of the clicked element.

Comment: @crush I totally agree, that's why I asked it, to point out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the text presented to the user as a source of data is not a good idea. For example, what if you decide later to support other languages or even use the abbreviated version (JAN,FEB etc.)? it will break your code. 
Remember: Always separate logic and presentation.

Instead, I'd give the months the same `data` attribute as the days `class`:

```
   <ul id="month" class="clearfix">
        <li data-month="january">January</li>
        <li data-month="february" class="active">February</li>
        <li data-month="march">March</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="day january">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="day february">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="day march">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#month>li").click(function(){

    // hide all months but the selected one

    $("#month>li").hide();
    $(this).show();

   // hide all but the days of the selected month

    current_month = $(this).data("month");
    $(".day").hide();
    $(".day."+current_month).show();
});
```

You'll also notice that I removed a lot of bloated unnecessary HTML. There is still more to remove and reconstruct, but I'll leave it to you (e.g How about wrapping all the days lists with a div  - that is, namespacing them - and removing the repeating `.day` class from the individual ul's?).

Last note: when using an event handler for a group of elements, you don't need to attach the function to each element individually - Instead, use script to bind the event to all the elements in question with one declaration - as shown above - and stay DRY.

Comment: Thanks this is a great explanation, will try to do this way

Answer (score 3):

Try this function:

```
function calendaractive(that){
    var text = $(that).text().toLowerCase();
    $('ul.day').each(function(o){
        if($(this).hasClass(text)) {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        }
    });
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/picklespy/CDcLy/2/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this -

```
function calendaractive(that){
       $('.day').filter(function(){
             var text = $.trim($(that).text().toLowerCase());
             return  $(this).hasClass(text);
       }).fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modified your code to this. Tested

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>

 <ul id="month" class="clearfix">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="january" onclick="calendaractive(this.id);">January</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="february" onclick="calendaractive(this.id);">February</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="march" onclick="calendaractive(this.id);">March</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="day january">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="day february">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="day march">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>


<script>

 function calendaractive(that){
    $(".day").fadeOut(0.5);
    $("."+that).fadeIn();
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if in late, the shortest:

`function calendaractive(that){
        $('.day:not(.'+$(that).html().toLowerCase()+')').fadeOut();
        $('.day'+'.'+$(that).html().toLowerCase()).fadeIn();
}`